# Authentication spring Security in angular 5

Tags: angular

i'm using an existing code in angular 4 and i'm trying to change it to angular 5 : 
    in this part i have an auth.service.ts where i have the error :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {User} from '../model/model.user';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
 @Injectable()
 export class AuthService {
   constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  public logIn(user: User) {

const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json')
const base64Credential: string = btoa( user.username + ':' + user.password);
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64Credential);

this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/' + '/account/login', {
  headers: headers}).map(resp => {
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
// this line where i have a problem : 
    user = resp.json().principal; // the returned user object is a principal object
    if (user) {
      // store user details  in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
  });
    }

      logOut() {
// remove user from local storage to log user out
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8081' + 'logout', {})
  .map(resp => {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  });

  }
   }
```

if there are any changes that i have to make please tell me
the acctual error is :

```
  error :src/services/auth.service.ts(19,21): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Comment: try `map(resp: any  => {` once

Comment: Sboui, I added an answer, Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add type `any` to the `resp`

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/' + '/account/login', { headers: headers}).map(resp: any => 
    {
        user = resp.json().principal; 
        if (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `resp.json()` in the map operator because **HttpClient** will handle it for us. we don't need to parse into JSON again.

```
public logIn(user: User) {

const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json')
const base64Credential: string = btoa( user.username + ':' + user.password);
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64Credential);

this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/' + '/account/login', {headers)
  .map(resp => {
    // this response is already parsed into a JSON by HttpClient. We don't need to do that explicitly
    // do something
    return resp;
  })
  ...
 }
```

Comment: how will it be? (if i remove this resp.json)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/' + '/account/login', {
  headers: headers}).subscribe(resp => {
    user = resp['principal'];
    if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
});
```

Hope this answer is solve your issue